# Making DialogFragment window scrollable

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I'm having a problem where Dialogs don't scroll when their content is too large for the screen. I assume this is because `Dialogs` are not displayed within Scrollable containers.

[image]

*Screenshot contains content wrapped in a ScrollView - You can see only the content is scrollable*

*Extra fields added to artificially increase dialog size  for this example*

You can see from the [Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) that Dialogs should be wrapped within DialogFragments (This gives the benefit of having your dialogs survive an orientation change and response to lifecycle events) and this is the set up I'm trying to make work.

Much of the other answers I've found are all similar to one another and revolve around ensuring the window is set to "adjustResize". However, this would only make the parent view smaller on keyboard opening, it wouldn't make a View scrollable if it wasn't in a Scrollable container.

If someone could let me know if they have info to make a Dialog scrollable or to confirm that you cannot make a Dialog scrollable I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

I have achieved scrolling in dialog fragment,

Dialog layout design

```
<LinearLayout>
 <NestedScrollView>
   <ConstrainLayout>
   </ConstrainLayout>
 </NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In DialogFrament class ,

```
override fun onStart() {
  super.onStart()
       dialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZ)
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping everything in the NestedScrollView worked without the outer LinearLayout

Comment: @Jeffrey But isn't the LinearLayout necessary and good practice adding it?

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly the dirtiest and most likely to break solution to this problem:

After creating the Dialog in `onCreateDialog()` but before returning it you can achieve scrolling by adding this code:

```
    final ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    content.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            content.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            View inner = content.getChildAt(0);
            content.removeViewAt(0);
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getContext());
            scrollView.addView(inner);
            content.addView(scrollView);
        }
    });
```

Comment: coming up with dirty hacks like this really is an art :D well done for stating the fact +1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with DialogFragment, but I changed:

```
<fragment android:layout_height="425dp"
...
```

to this:

```
<fragment android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
...
```

And now it's scrolling when the keyboard is open, or when the screen is in landscape mode.

NOTE: I have ScrollView as a rootView in DialogFragment layout, of course.